# android: filter arrayList with 2 strings in adapter

Tags: android, string, arraylist, filter, android-filterable

I have an ArrayList where I only want to show the Items that contain the strings "dish" or "sideDish". At first I had a for-loop in the getItem function but it wasn't good for the performance so I tried to do it with a filter.

```
public Filter getFilter(){
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        String filterString= constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        final List<CanteenMenu> list = listData;

        int count = list.size();
        final List<CanteenMenu> nlist = new ArrayList<CanteenMenu>(count);

        String filterableString;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains("dish" || "sideDish")){
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }
        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<CanteenMenu>) results.values;
    }
}
```

The problems are:
- the or || doens't work
- the `filterableString = list.get(i);` gives the error icompatible types
- `nlist.add(filterableString);` gives the error list cannot be applied to string

Can anyone help?

Comment: "dish" || "sideDish" - will this even compile?

Comment: and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Is your list sorted? Otherwise any filtering will have to loop it in any case

Comment: @TimCastelijns added the problems above!

Comment: @EugenMartynov that's right that I need a loop in the filter but before I only had a loop in the getItem class which worked but had a bad influence to the performance

Comment: Are you using Kotlin or Scala or Groovy? Because `"dish" || "sideDish"` is not compilable in java

Comment: @EugenMartynov (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains("dish") | filterableString.toLowerCase().contains("sideDish") this brings no error. I use Java in AndroidStudio

Comment: Are you mixing `String` and `CanteenMenu`?

Comment: CanteenMenu is my ArrayList